# uncaught typeError can not read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, module

I have two javascript.One is for reading image file which i called 'register.js'.There i have a js module like the following

```
var FileUpload = (function (fileElement) {
  //code goes here other functions and stuff
  function fileread (event) {
    //code goes here
  }

  return {
    files: fileread // assign fileread as property and return
  };  
}(document.getElementById('up')))
```

I have added another file called 'call.js' which will use the FileUpload object to read the file when 'onChange' event occurs

```
function load () {
  console.log(FileUpload.files);
  document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('change', FileUpload.files,false);
}

window.onload=load;
```

But wherever I run the code I get the following error. How I can fix this error?

> create:115 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of
>   undefined

Comment: you need to pass in FileUpload to the load function somehow...it says that it cannot find that, how are you passing that in? why have it in two separate files?

Comment: i want to create a separate module for file upload functionality

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you've forgotten to use `module.exports` and `require`. At the end of `register.js`, add:

```
module.exports = FileUpload;
```

At the beginning of `call.js`, add:

```
var FileUpload = require('./register');
```

You will need to change `./register` to be the directory to register.js. The `.js` extension can be omitted because node assumes javascript files.

Comment: But i have added the two script on the same page.Shouldn't it work that way?

Comment: this is not a good answer, require wont automatically work on the front end unless he's using the proper build tool, ie Webpack...

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
return
      {
         files:fileread// assign fileread as property and return
      };
```

**Semicolons in Javascript are optional** so it doesn't know that you want to **return { files: fileread }**.  It thinks return is one statement and **{ files: fileread };** is a different statement.

Change to this and everything should work:

```
return {
    files:fileread// assign fileread as property and return
};
```